# Search a Linked List

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I want to make a phone book prototype project with a linked list using Java SE.
I need to store data like first name, last name, mobile, home, and office.

Actually, I want to know how I can search this type of data from a `LinkedList` using

```
public Node search(String key){

    Node current=first;

    while(current.data == null ? key != null : !current.data.equals(key))
        if(current.next==null)
            return null;
        else
            current=current.next;
        return current;

}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use Map?

Comment: Here's a hint: if you're a java noob don't use ternary Kung Fu

Comment: where is LinkedList defined?

Comment: Hints: LinkedList might not well suited for your purpose unless the exercise explicitly wants you to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't write my own LinkedList, but assuming this is homework I would write it like this.

```
public Node search(String key){
    for(Node n = first; n != null; n = n.next)
        if(isEqu(n.data, key))
            return n;
    return null;
}

private static boolean isEqu(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return o1 == null ? o2 == null : o1.equals(o2);
}
```